# Divi Builder - dynamic content for contact forms

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a CPT of Hotels in my Wordpress Website, and I have a specific footer for this CPT (i.e. applies to all hotels), which contains a contact form.

Currently, when a user send me an email I don't know from which hotel this email came from.

How could I interactively add some dynamic text to the message that I could identify the hotel (for example, showing me the page title, or the page link in which the form was sent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Set the form "id" to "hotel-reservation".
2. Add a hidden input to your form and set the id to "reference".
3. Add this js code to your global javascript:

   ```
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

      $("#hotel-reservation").submit(function(){
         $('input#reference').val( $(location).attr('href') );
      });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Is the form hard-coded? You could use a hidden field within the form with `value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"` or `<?php the_title(); ?>`